# scaleUpTime and scaleDownTime cron expressions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I've recently inhertied some cloud formation scripts.

I can see that someone has written my cloudFormation scripts with the following....

```
        "SelfTerminatingScaleUpScheduledAction":{
            "Type":"AWS::AutoScaling::ScheduledAction",
             ...
             ...
                "Recurrence":{
                    "Ref":"ScaleUpTme"
                }
            }
        },
```

And then...

```
        "ScaleUpTme":{
            "Description":"Autoscale up at a particular time every day",
            "Type":"String",
            "Default":"15 20 * * 0-4",
            "AllowedValues" : [ "cronEpression1","cronEpression2","cronEpression3", "cronEpression4","cronEpression5","cronEpression6", "cronEpression7","cronEpression8"]        
        },
```

I have taken out the actual cron expressions.

It looks like there is a cron expresison for every day of the week? But I am a bit confused about why there are 8 cron expressions specified. Can someone explain more to me on this.

Also the real cron expression appearing in the AllowedValues look to be using z time rather than local time. Can someone confirm that to me please?

I tried to find the documentation for this in AWS but couldn't quite find the right page.

thanks

Comment: Those are weird, and they are misspelled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AllowedValues` is used with **parameters**, which are questions asked when a CloudFormation template is launched. The user can then select one of the values, and it is substituted into the (sort of) variable called *ScaleUpTme*.

Thus, the line that says `"Ref":"ScaleUpTme"` will automatically insert the chosen parameter value, which in your case is a cron expression.

There are 8 specified so that, presumably, the user can choose the desired cron expression at the time of launching the stack.

The cron schedules for Auto Scaling are **always in UTC**. There is no concept of 'local time'. (This is pretty standard with worldwide infrastructure, to avoid confusion with timezones and daylight savings.)

Documentation: [Scheduled Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/schedule_time.html)